# Is there a command line ATI texture compression tool?

Tags: tools, textures, compression

Is there a command line tool that can convert PNG and JPG files to ATITC compressed textures?

I have my own export pipeline that converts all textures to PVRTC, ATITC, and DXT, so I have no use for a GUI-based tool like the Compressonator. Also, I'm running on Linux (although Wine might be able to handle simple conversion tools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compressonator can be used through the command line.

```
TheCompressonator <-command> [options]
Commands:
  help     - display help
  convert  - convert image type to another, or compress
  diff     - compare textures
  plugins  - get list of plugins and their options
```

Comment: Indeed! It's quite terrible under Wine, and I haven't gotten it to work yet... but I guess that's the only option.

Comment: Based on a quick search it looks like the compressonator is the only way to do it. There's some hints that some SDK used to support it as well, so one might be able to roll your own tool, but nothing concrete. See this thread for some clues: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=262790

Comment: Oh well... I decided to run the compressonator under VirtualBox, which can access my Linux file system, so I can still fully automate it. And at least I can do all my DXT textures with the same tool too.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: ImgTec has both a [texture compression utility](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) and a [texture compression library](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp) (which works under both Linux and Windows). They support some compressed texture formats, like DXT and PVRTC.

Rolling out your own command-line tool is easy as pie using the library. I'm currently adding PVRTC support for my XNA pipeline (the processor is made with Managed-C++) and haven't found any problems yet.

Comment: Thanks! I've use the PVRTexTool on Linux and it works like a charm. Still no solution for the ATI tool, it doesn't work right under Wine. I've actually resigned to using PVR and ETC only at this point. I'll consider DXT5 for alpha textures.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the compressonator to run under Ubuntu 12.04 by first running

```
winetricks vcrun2005
```

then copying the installed compressonator files to ~/.wine/drive_c and running it from there with

```
wine TheCompressonator.exe
```

Comment: I need `vcrun2015` instead for `TheCompressonatorCLI.exe` V2.3.2953 and override `api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0` to use native first (see winecfg). I'm on macOS 10.12

Answer (score 1):

**Andreno SDK** provides a windows library to compress your texture without Compressonator. You can build your **own tool** to convert PNG, BMP, TGA or JPEG to ATITC on windows platform.

Otherwise, Unity3D which is running on OS X and windows generates ATITC for mobile assets, but i don't find the internal tool which does it (No wine too).

NB: our build system can compress to ETC, PVR and DXT on Win, OSX and Linux but for ATITC we zip all src images, send them to a server and use ATI Compressonator to compress them and download them when it's done.

NB 2: use PVRTextTool for PVR, it is faster or better than textureTool (Apple's one).